# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to post JSON Serialized data into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I have:

```
public class LoanInfoVM
{
    [Required]
    public string LoanType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int LoanAmount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Installments { get; set; }
    public string LoanData { get; set; }
}
```

EntityMapper:

```
public class EntityMapper
{
    public LoanInfo FromLoanInfoVMToLoan(LoanInfoVM loan)
    {
        LoanInfo loan = new LoanInfo()
        {
            LoanType = loan.LoanType,
            LoanAmount = loan.LoanAmount,
            Installments = loan.Installments,
        };

        string loanJsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loan);
        return loan;
    }
}
```

LoanService:

```
    public async Task<LoanInfo> Post(LoanInfoVM loan)
    {
        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var loanDt = mapper.FromLoanInfovmToLoanInfo(loan);

        await _unitOfWork.LoanRepository.Insert(loanDt);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

        return loan;
    }
```

The model consists of `LoanType`, `LoanAmount`, `Installments`, `LoanData`.

`LoanData` is JsonSerializer for `LoanType`, `LoanAmount`, `Installments`.

I am only able to insert `LoanType,LoanAmount,Installments`.

But how do I include `LoanData` also which is `JsonSerializer.Serialize(loan)`?

I want to be able to do all these into the same model `LoanInfo` at the same submit.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow. Are you saying you want to insert the json representation of a loan into the same row as its other fields? First, why? Second, just insert it as a string field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapper you could add

```
public class EntityMapper
{
    public LoanInfo FromLoanInfoVMToLoan(LoanInfoVM loan)
    {
        LoanInfo loan = new LoanInfo()
        {
            LoanType = loan.LoanType,
            LoanAmount = loan.LoanAmount,
            Installments = loan.Installments,
        };
        loan.LoanData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loan)
        return loan;
    }
}
```

You have the variable `loanJsonData` but you never use it.